# sts 3.6.1: default server is not added to workspace; cannot select tomcat7 for Pivotal 3.0

Tags: spring-tool-suite, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

When I was using `STS 3.6.0` a default 'Servers' folder `(Vmware vFabric v2.5 - v.2.9)` was always added to any new workspace I created.
Since installing `STS 3.6.1` I am no longer seeing a default 'Server' being attached to the workspace.
It appears that `STS 3.6.1` is now bundling `Pivotal tc Server v3.0`, which appears to favor Tomcat 8 for the default underlying binary (this requires Java SE 7, but I need to use Java SE 6(which is my workspace default))
So my best guess as to why the automatic addition of the 'Servers' folder is not occurring, is that I don't have Java SE7 set as my workspace default, but I'm a little surprised that Tomcat 8 is being considered the default binary for tc Server;

I am also having issues manually adding a server for my workspace

```
(e.g. New->Server->Pivotal tcServer v3.0)
```

After I select the location for the `'Pivotal tcServer v3.0'` the default Tomcat version selected is `Tomcat 8.0.9.B.RELEASE`.  I get the following warning after this selection:

```
"Tomcat 8 requires Java SE7 or later. Change the JRE to one that meets this requirement"
```

Understood, but...

When I select `Tomcat 7.0.55.A.RELEASE` as the Version, I still see the same message and I am unable to proceed with adding the server.(Its my understanding that Tomcat 7.x is supported by Java SE6).
This is unexpected behavior in my opinion since my workspace default JRE supports Tomcat 7.  Is there anyway around this issue?

Answer (score 6):

1. From the main menu, open **Window -> Preferences**.
2. Then, navigate to the **Server -> Runtime Environments** page.
3. At the top of the list you should be able to see **Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition (Runtime)**. Select it and then press "**Edit...**" button.
4. In the dialog that appears, select your **JRE** and **Tomcat versions** from the appropriate dropdowns. Press the "**Finish**" button to save your changes and create a new server instance.
5. Start the created server and you'll see that Tomcat 7.0.55 starts.
   Please raise a defect if you feel that 7.0.55 should be the default rather than 8.x.

Comment: The Server->Runtime Environments list is initially empty. So I click `Add...` , select `Pivotal tc Server v3.0,` and browse to the `pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE` folder. As previously mentioned `Tomcat 8.0.9.B.RELEASE` is selected by default and is accompanied by the `...requires Java SE 7...` message; however, switching to `Tomcat 7.0.55.A.RELEASE` does not remove the message and I am unable to proceed as the `Next` and `Finish` buttons are grayed out. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this. That was a bug indeed. The wizard page should be revalidated if tomcat version has been changed. This should be fixed now. Also some support for using various versions of VMs available via Eclipse's Installed JREs (i.e. JRE's different from Java Home on the system).
Please try updating your tc server eclipse integration from this update: http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/eclipse-integration-tcserver/nightly I think the fix is already available in the latest build.

Comment: P.S. Tomcat 8.0 will be left as default for tc server 3.0 default runtime, so you'd have to create your own runtime environment for Java 6 + Tomcat 7.0.55 via Preferences, Server -> Runtime Environments